# vmware workstation tools mountain lion mac OS x

Tags: vmware, vmware-tools

I installed **Mountain Lion** and then I tried to run and then got this error:

```
The virtual machine cannot enter Unity mode because:
- The guest operating system does not have VMware Tools installed.
- The guest operating system's resolution cannot be changed.
```

Then I try to update tools:

```
Could not find component on update server.
Contact VMware Support or your system administrator.
```

Answer (score 13):

Arkadi's answer is right, here are the detailed actions:

(See also **[this post](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/vmware-tools-cannot-be-installed-on-mac-os-x-could-not-find-component/)** for more snapshots)

- Download [darwin.iso](https://www.dropbox.com/s/da54fkumcryk4p0/darwin.iso).
- **Right click** your virtual machine in vmware
- Click the **settings** menu item
- Select **CD/DVD** item in the left UI
- On the right UI, select and mount the darwin.iso.

[image]

Now, the vmware tools installation is started in your Mac OSX virtual machine:

[image]

Comment: i still get the "The guest operating system's resolution cannot be changed." error message after i installed darwin.iso and latest VMsvga2 driver. I have VMWare 10.1 and Mac OS X 10.9. Do you have any further suggestions what can be done here?..

Answer (score 12):

You can download VMWare Tools and graphic driver from here:

- [VMware_Tools](http://www.mediafire.com/download/911bvp006dz14or/Install_VMware_Tools.zip)
- [Graphic Driver - VMsvga2](http://www.mediafire.com/download/cv8vqbz2mdpxyi5/VMsvga2_v1.2.5_OS_10.6-10.8.pkg)

Comment: Some background info, those links came from this [link](http://www.souldevteam.net/blog/2012/06/15/os-x-mountain-lion-10-8-dp4-vmware-image-release-notes-links/)

Comment: Check the answers below before you try this!

Answer (score 8):

The links supplied in Boris M answer points to software that is outdated and opens ad-ware sites in browser after install.

Here are the official [darwin.iso](https://www.dropbox.com/s/da54fkumcryk4p0/darwin.iso) (9MB) and [darwin.iso.sig](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6dlo6x0u4myue2/darwin.iso.sig) files from VMware Fusion 6.0.4 for Mac. Put it into vmware/isoimages/ folder next to other ISO files.

Unfortunately, VM > Install VMware Tools menu entry still won't work, so attach the ISO manually and install the package.

Comment: Again, taking stuff from dropbox is slightly weird to me, [here's a Github repo](https://github.com/DrDonk/unlocker) that is updated frequently with everything you need to install VMware with a OSX guest, including the vmware-tools. Upon running the `gettools.py` python script, you'll have a `tools/` directory with `darwin.iso`. This script pulls the latest official vmware darwin.iso image.